# How to install gzopen library on CentOS 6.4?

Tags: linux, centos-6, c++

I'm compiling a program using gzopen library. How can I install this library in CentOS 6.4?

I have tried to install it with yum but package not found!

> No package **gzopen** available!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use yum to install zlib-devel . I mean this command:

```
yum install zlib-devel
```